# Reference the Anchor element on OnSuccess Ajax.ActionLink

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 3 with jquery.unobtrusive-ajax, and I want to hide a link after ajax is completed. Can I do something like this?

```
@(Ajax.ActionLink("Disapprove", "Disapprove", "Comment", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "POST", OnSuccess = "$(this).remove();"}))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Ajax.ActionLink(
    "Disapprove",
    "Disapprove",
    "Comment",
    null,
    new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "POST",
        OnSuccess = "remove"
    },
    new
    {
        id = "mylink"
    }
)
```

and then in a separate function:

```
function remove() {
    $('#mylink').remove();
}
```

Comment: Darin, I want to refer "this", not the id. Just for convenience. Using asp.net mvc I always need to think how I can make all ID´s uniques, no matter if my view is used with Partial, inside a loop, etc...

Comment: @Fujiy, then use normal `Html.ActionLink` and subscribe for the .click event to send the AJAX request manually. Inside you will be able to capture the element that sent the request.

Comment: Its an option, but I'm not believing that something trivial as reference $(this) is not possible

Comment: Is there a way to get a reference to `this` at the `remove` function? In my scenario I have many generated links and I want to rely on the id, instead I need a reference to `this`. Is that possible?

Comment: @Shimmy, yes it is possible, but you'd better use a standard Html.ActionLink for that which you could AJAXify.

Comment: Obviously I prefer to keep my code as clean as possible, and not pollute it with redundant JavaScript code. So I'm still hoping there is a way to get a reference to the anchor and keep on using the Ajax method.

Comment: @Shimmy, no, I am afraid that there's no way to achieve that with the built-in Ajax.* helpers. It's a limitation and one of the reasons why I never use them.

Answer (score 1):

For the life of me I could not get this to work with an AjaxOptions method.  However, just adding a standard jquery event to the link should work: `$("a").click(function () { $(this).remove(); });`.  That will do all a tags, so you'll want to update it just to do the one you wish...

Comment: I can´t do that. I need to remove when OnSuccess mehod is called

Comment: bear in mind that OnSuccess is only saying the Ajax call was made successfully, not that the action succeeded.